# Prevent next div if required fieds missing

Tags: javascript, html, divide

I m using the followin js to hide and show DIVS using next and previous buttons
It works fine but now I want it to prevent displaying the next DIV if the required fields on current diplayed DIV is missing

```
var counter=1;
```

// Close All  tab

```
function all_tab_hide()
{
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
    $("#tab_"+i).hide();
    }
 }
```

// Show next Function

```
function show_tab_next(i)
{
    reqf();
    if (counter>=3){
    counter=3;
    }
    var tabno=counter;

    all_tab_hide();

    $("#tab_"+tabno).show();

    if(tabno=='1')
    {
        $("#btn_pre").hide();
        $("#btn_next").hide();
        $("#btn_start").show();
    }else{
        $("#btn_pre").show();
        $("#btn_next").show();
        $("#btn_start").hide();

    }

 }
```

//Show Previous function

```
 function show_tab_pre(i)
 {
    var tabno=counter;
    all_tab_hide();
    $("#tab_"+tabno).show();
    if(tabno=='1')
    {
         $("#btn_pre").hide();
        $("#btn_next").hide();
        $("#btn_start").show();
    }else{
         $("#btn_pre").show();
        $("#btn_next").show();
        $("#btn_start").hide();


    }    
 }

  // Tab 1 and button next Show on starting point

 $( document ).ready(function() {
 all_tab_hide();
 $("#tab_1").show();
 $("#btn_pre").hide();
 $("#btn_next").hide();
 });
```